# VBA code to numerically fill a series starting with one that counts the number of active rows in range

Tags: vba, loops

I am looking to have a series filled in sequentially dependent on the number of active rows. What is the best way to do this? My formula below is adding one too many numbers to the rows. I want it to go from 1 to 70 but it is adding in a 71, too.
[image]

```
Sub copy_sequenc_down()


    Dim maxRowIndex As Integer

    maxRowIndex = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count

    'set up starting point of repetition structure
    Range("a2").Select
    Dim rowCounter As Integer
    rowCounter = 1

    'begin populating sequence
    For rowCounter = 1 To maxRowIndex
        'populate number in sequence
        ActiveCell = rowCounter
        'go to next row
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Show an example of what you're after and what you tried so far?

Comment: If you click on the word, "spreadsheet", in my post, you will see image of my sheet.

Comment: Cool image. But yet no code attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faster to set them all at once:

```
Set rng = Range("A2").Resize(Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1)
rng.Formula = "=ROW()-1"
rng.Value2 = rng.Value2     ' optional to change the formulas to values
```

or a bit more advanced:

```
rng.Value2 = Evaluate("ROW(1:" & rng.Rows.Count & ")")
```

---

A bit easier with [structured references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) if you format the range as Table:

```
[Table1[Column1]] = [Row(Table1[Column1])-1]
```

or

```
[Table1[Column1]] = [Row(Table1[Column1])-Row(Table1[#Headers])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copy_sequenc_down()

    Dim maxRowIndex As Integer

    maxRowIndex = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count

    'set up starting point of repetition structure
    Range("a2").Select
    Dim rowCounter As Integer
    rowCounter = 1

    'begin populating sequence
    For rowCounter = 1 To maxRowIndex - 1
        'populate number in sequence
        ActiveCell = rowCounter
        'go to next row
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code down by looping the range

```
Sub copy_sequenc_down()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell in Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        cell.Value = rowCounter
    Next
End Sub
```